# RobotFramework ImportError: No module named foo

Tags: java, keyword, robotframework

I have a class in Java which looks like this:

```
package com.charandeepmatta.keywords;
import org.robotframework.javalib.annotation.RobotKeyword;
import org.robotframework.javalib.annotation.RobotKeywords;

@RobotKeywords
public class SampleKeywords {
    @RobotKeyword
    public void printToErrorStream() {
        System.err.println("!!! Hello from keyword developed in java ...");
    }
}
```

And my test case looks like this

```
*** Settings ***
Library  org.robotframework.javalib.library.AnnotationLibrary  /**.class

*** Test Cases ***
Keyword defined in java class can print to error stream
   Print To Error Stream
```

When I try to run it on RIDE it gives me the following error

```
    [ ERROR ] Error in file 'C:\Users\BFerreira\git\robotframework-maven-project\src\main\robot\suite\OwnDevelopedKeywordTestCase.txt': 
Importing test library 'org.robotframework.javalib.library.AnnotationLibrary' failed: 
ImportError: No module named org.robotframework.javalib.library
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      None
    PYTHONPATH:
      C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robot\libraries
      C:\Python27\lib\site-packages
      C:\Windows\system32\python27.zip
      C:\Python27\DLLs
      C:\Python27\lib
      C:\Python27\lib\plat-win
      C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk
      C:\Python27
      C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode
      .
      C:\Users\user1\git\robotframework-maven-project\src\main\robot\suite
```

Everything is in the same classpath, can anyone help?

Comment: It seems like the issue is with this:: Library  org.robotframework.javalib.library.AnnotationLibrary, is it possible that the classpath is wrong? maybe org.robotframework.javalib.AnnotationLibrary ?

Comment: This is a code from GIT: https://github.com/cdmatta/robotframework-maven-project I think that library is inside javalib-core-1.0.1.jar and I actually tried to use the jar itself but keeps giving me the same error

Answer (score 2):

From the looks of your output, you are not [executing with jybot/Jython](https://code.google.com/p/robotframework/wiki/JavaIntegration). Jython is required to load Java classes in a Python interpreter. Here is what the output would look like if you were:

```
PYTHONPATH:
  C:\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages
  C:\apps\jython2.5.3\Lib\site-packages\setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg
  C:\apps\jython2.5.3\Lib\site-packages\pip-1.2.1-py2.5.egg
  C:\apps\jython2.5.3\Lib
  __classpath__
  __pyclasspath__/
  C:\apps\jython2.5.3\Lib\site-packages
  .
  c:\ws\local
CLASSPATH:
  C:\apps\jython2.5.3\jython.jar
```

A word of caution: if you run the Robot Framework jar (e.g. java -jar robotframework-2.5.3.jar ...) as some examples suggest, all classpath settings are ignored. You would have to put all your dependencies in one jar for that way to work...

Comment: Although that corrects my execution it still gives the the error of no module found. Do you're saying to put jython.jar and MyLibrary.jar in one jar?

Comment: I was not suggesting to do that, just warning about a common mistake others make.